# Change the size/width of tabs in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Is there any way to change the width or the size of tabs in Notepad++? I usually have many tabs open, and it makes it hard to see all of them at once because I need to press the arrow keys to see which one is where. In other words, notepad++ doesn't resize tabs at all.

In a normal browser, tabs are resized according to how many you have. If you have too many, then they are squeezed together.

This is exactly what I want to achieve. Is there perhaps an extension that does this for Notepad++?

I'd also like to add that I'd rather not use the document switcher. I have the reduce tab size option enabled, but unfortunately it doesn't make it much better!

Answer (score 3):

#### Is there any way to change the width or the size of tabs in Notepad++?

You can reduce the size of the tabs:

- Menu > "Preferences"
- Select "General"
- In the "Tab Bar" section check "Reduce"
- Click "Close"

  [image]

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I have that checked though. I was looking for something that would rather change the width of the tabs instead :)

Answer (score 3):

Did you see the "Multi-line" checkbox on the screenshot above? That helped me solving my - I think similar - problem.